# How to hide loaded comments in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a jQuery code that loads `More comments` of a post via AJAX. The `More comments` is afterward replaced with `Less comments` 
which is expected to hide the loaded comments but it is not working...

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class = 'feeds'>
  <div class = 'comments'>
    <div class = 'comment_data>
      <div class = 'per_comment'>
        <p> slideToggle!</p>
      </div>
      <div class = 'per_comment'>
        <p> classToggle!</p>
      </div>
    <button class='morecomments' value='7' name = 'more' type='submit'>
     More comments</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code that loads more comments, and it works just fine:

```
$(".morecomments").click(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var post_id = $(this).val();
  var request = $.ajax({
  url: "comments.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { post : post_id },
  dataType: "html"
  });
request.done(function( msg ) {
   $this.prev('.per_comment').html( msg ); 
   $this.replaceWith("<button class='lesscomments value='7' name = 'less'   type='submit'>Less comments</button>"); 
});
});
```

jQuery code that I expect to hide the loaded comments but it is not working:

```
$( ".lesscomments" ).click(function() {
var $this=$(this);
$(".murconform").submit(function(e){
        return false;
    });
    $this.prev('.comment_data').slideToggle('fast')
});
```

Anticipatory thanks.

Comment: There are few more issues.. the comment_data element is not a prev sibling it is an ancestor element, also what is the purpose of the submit handler in the click function... try `$(".murconform").submit(function (e) {
    return false;
});

$('.comment_data').on('click', ".lesscomments", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.comment_data').slideToggle('fast')
});`

Comment: `closest` did the trick. You just made my sleepless night a productive one. Thanks!

Comment: again what was the purpose of the submit handler

Comment: also edited my answer

Comment: The submit handler wasn't supposed to be there. T'was supposed to be edited out. Thank you, once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the less comments element is created dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
//this should not be within the less handler.... need to handle the logic in some other way
$(".murconform").submit(function (e) {
    return false;
});
$('.comment_data').on('click', ".lesscomments", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.comment_data').slideToggle('fast')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the lesscomments element does not exist in the page when it is loading. 
And you should be using document.ready to eetuar action.
 Try to use the function on: http://api.jquery.com/on/